# Passing byte array as parameter to stored procedure in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, arrays

I have function, which I need to put in Oracle Database (I'm using 11g) as stored procedure. Suppose that this function looks like this:

```
public static BLOB useByteArray(byte[] byteArray){
    //do something with this byte array, return BLOB with something
}
```

So how should wrapper function looks? I know it will be something around this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USE_BYTE_ARRAY(byteArray ???) RETURN BLOB IS
 LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'com.example.something.useByteArray(byte[]???)';
```

but I have no idea how can I pass this byte array between wrapper and java function. Perhaps, encode it in Base64, pass as string and then encode in `useByteArray` method?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use [OracleTypes.BLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleTypes.html#BLOB) to pass the data from your java application and you can consume it with the `blob` data type in your stored procedure.

Comment: I know about this possilibity, but I'm looking for sending raw bytes. Probably I will use BLOB, but now I'm still trying ;)

Comment: You have to make oracle understand what you're sending and I guess that's what blob can be used for!

Comment: This is good answer, thank you :) However, in my specific situation base64 will be more useful - but `BLOB` is good option ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind requirement, you can use SYS REF CURSOR from oracle. We can send ARRAY of values to stored procedure.

1) SYS REF CURSOR Declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_CURSOR AS
```

TYPE testCursorType is REF CURSOR;
END;

2) Create ORACLE type of table for accepting ARRAY

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tabletype AS TABLE OF NUMBER(10);
```

3) Create your procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testProc
(adeptno tabletype,
testFetch IN OUT test_cursor.testCursorType) AS
BEGIN
OPEN testFetch FOR 
SELECT * 
FROM emp
WHERE deptno IN (SELECT *
FROM TABLE(CAST(adeptno AS tabletype)));
END;
```

4) And finally JAVA code

```
private static final String ARRAY_PROCEDURE = "call testProc(?,?)";
int arrayElements[] = {10,20,30,40};
//Create an Array Descriptor
ArrayDescriptor deptdesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TABLETYPE",connObj);
//Define the Array (Descriptor,connection, Elements)
ARRAY deptarray = new ARRAY(deptdesc, connObj, arrayElements);
this.executePrepareQuery(conn, ARRAY_PROCEDURE,deptarray);
```

Comment: I'm looking for answer how to match  `byte[]`type  parameter in java method with wrapper to call it in oracle ;)

Comment: Yes I got it, to achieve this you should have JAVA class with you in oracle so you can execute the same class from Oracle stored procedure. see this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm